# Is an Outlook Storage Item synced to Exchange

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I am having some trouble with an Outlook Addin. The Outlook Addin consists of a COM part and a Web part. After digging into the Logs of that Outlook Addin i was able to figure out that the Plugin first creates a Storage Item and then writes some Information into it.

I would like to ask the Wizards of StackOverflow whether a StorageItem in Outlook's Inbox with all it's Information is synced to Exchange. If I have multiple PCs setup with the same Email but only use the Outlook Addin on one of those PCs, will that one PC sync that StorageItem created by the Outlook Addin including it's data to Exchange and as a result to all the other PCs/Outlook Inboxes where the same Email is being used?

The other question I have is whether there is a Windows Tool that can display all Storage Items present in the Inbox and even delete a StorageItem if needed. I know the ID of the StorageItem from the Logs and i am pretty sure that all such StorageItems are a part of the .ost File.

The Exchange Version in use is 365 and there are 4 different PCs with the same Email setup in all 4 Outlooks. 2 of those PCs have Outlook 2016 and the remaining 2 have Outlook 365.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Outlook synchronizes both regular and associated (hidden) folder contents table. From the MAPI point of view, `StorageItem` is just another message similar to `MailItem`, only it resides in the folder contents table invisible to the end user.

You can see associated items in any folder using [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMAPIFolder, go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

Keep in mind that web addin private data is not stored in the Inbox, it is stored in a folder outside of the IPM folder tree invisible to the end user. I don't think *that* folder is synchronized in the cached mode.

Comment: Thank You for your answer Dmitry. I have downloaded and installed Outlook Spy. I found the Storage. Can Outlook Spy also find the addin private data outside of the IPM Folder?

Comment: If I remember correctly, addin data is stored in subfolders of the "ApplicationData" folder, which is a child of the top store folder. You'd need to either turn cached mode off, restart Outlook, click IMsgStore | "Open Folder". Or you can (if you want to stay in the cached mode), start with Inbox, click IMAPIFolder, select PR_PARENT_ENTRYID, right click, "IMAPISession::OpenEntry", make sure "MAPI_NO_CACHE" is checked. Repeat one for time for the Inbox parent - that will get you to the top folder in the store. Then you can drill down to the child folders from the GetHierarchyTable tab.